# Locations around the users with parse

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

Hi i developp an application and I would want to ask a question plz

In my data cloud Parse , i have class ” restaurants ” i have three columns : ” name ” type string ; “imageFile” type file ; "description ” type array and "Location" type GeoPoint.

I would want to know which method to use to get back current GeoPoint of the user?
Then I would want to know how to compare GeoPoint of users and those of the restaurants to post(show) finally in TableView restaurants the closest to the user in kilometers.

Answer (score 2):

To get the user's position, you can use the following function: `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` you would then create a query that uses the current location to find points that are near the user's location.

Code Example in Swift:

```
//Get the user's current location
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
    (point:PFGeoPoint!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        //Point contains the user's current point

        //Get a max of 100 of the restaurants that are within 5km,
        //ordered from nearest to furthest
        var query = PFQuery(className: "restaurants")
        query.limit = 100
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: point, withinKilometers: 5.0)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                //objects contains the restaurants
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please i don't very understand , where i add this function ?

Comment: This will go in you iOS code (wherever you want to get the objects). Note it runs asynchronously so you'll need to reload the view once objects are retrieved.